# Can using volatile with "AtomicInteger" guarantees thread safety?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, volatile

Suppose I have

```
private volatile AtomicInteger atomInt = new AtomicInteger(3);
```

and in methods my usage is `atomInt.incrementAndGet()`.

Since I am using `AtomicInteger`, it will avoid "thread interference". And then I am using volatile, so it will guarantee the consistent view of the variable across all threads. Does it mean that I have got complete thread safety or still there are chances of "memory consistency issues"?

I got confused because of usage of "reduce" in [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), so it suggests me that there are still chances but I cannot think of it:

> Using volatile variables **reduces the risk of memory consistency
>   errors**, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a
>   happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same
>   variable.

Comment: Are you ever reassigning `atomInt` (as in `atomInt = ...`)? If not, make it final, not volatile. The volatile refers to the value of the variable, not to state in the thing the variable points to.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for your time to reply. Ok, I think then it would guarantee thread safety, right? But still I am looking for answer to my question.

Comment: The answer to your question is that you shouldn't need to use volatile if you are never reassigning the variable, and you may need to use it if you are.

Comment: @AndyTurner For sake of my "learning", lets say I am reassigning.

Comment: Ditto @AndyTurner.  Declare the variable to be `final`, not `volatile`.  If you are using an `AtomicInteger` variable and you _can't_ declare it to be `final` then you are either doing something very tricky, or what's more likely, something wrong.

Comment: Re, "Does it mean that I have got complete thread safety...?"  Complete thread safety is when your multi-threaded program is guaranteed to always do the right thing.  You haven't shown us a complete program, so there's no way to truly answer that question.  Thread safety is an attribute of the whole program's architecture. 
 It's not something you can bestow on a program one line at a time.

Comment: "Thread safety" is not a very well-defined term, at least it isn't one that is [formally defined in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4). But @jameslarge is right, you can only reason about a whole program, for example any code, no matter how bad, is "thread-safe" when run in a single thread. What you're really looking for is whether an otherwise correctly synchronised program would become incorrectly synchronised by the introduction of this code. And the answer to that is no.

Answer (score 4):

> And then I am using `volatile`, so it will guarantee the consistent view of the variable across all threads.

Thread-safety is already guaranteed by atomic variables. `volatile` is redundant if you won't reassign the variable. You can replace `volatile` with `final` here:

```
private final AtomicInteger atomInt = new AtomicInteger(3);
```

> Does it mean that I have got complete thread safety or still there are chances of "memory consistency issues"?

At this moment, it's absolutely thread-safe. No "memory consistency issues" might happen **with the variable**. But using proper thread-safe components **doesn't mean** that the whole class/program is thread-safe. Problems might take place if interactions between them are incorrect.

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors ...

`volatile` variables can only guarantee **visibility**. They don't guarantee [**atomicity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability).

As [Brian Goetz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) writes (emphasis mine):

> `volatile` variables are convenient, **but they have limitations**. The most common use for volatile variables is as a completion, interruption, or status flag. Volatile variables can be used for other kinds of state information, but more care is required when attempting this. For example, **the semantics of `volatile` are not strong enough to make the increment operation (`count++`) atomic**, unless you can guarantee that the variable is written only from a single thread.
>
> You can use volatile variables only when all the following criteria are met:
>
> - Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value, or you can ensure that only a single thread ever updates the value;
> - The variable does not participate in invariants with other state variables;
> - Locking is not required for any other reason while the variable is being accessed.

---

From the docs of the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package:

> - `get` has the memory effects of reading a `volatile` variable.
> - `set` has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a `volatile` variable.

Comment: But what about this from Java tutorials I have provided in my question - " Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference. **However, this does not eliminate all need to synchronize atomic actions, because memory consistency errors are still possible.**"

Comment: I am bit confused because of the description of "java.util.concurrent.atomic" package because without use of volatile or synchronized, "read barrier" and "write barrier" will not execute, and if they do not execute then there is no guarantee about flushing of cache values to main memory.

Comment: @pjj **The memory effects for accesses and updates of atomics generally follow the rules for volatiles, as stated in The Java Language Specification (17.4 Memory Model)**
as pointed out by @Andrew Tobilko
But if you need to atomically change several `Atomic`s or use check-then-act then you need additional synchronization

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the final is needed to make sure the reference to the AtomicInteger is seen by all threads?

Answer (score 1):

Volatile does mean that changes to the variable will be visible. But in this case you shouldn’t be changing the reference held by the variable.

It seems very odd that you’d want to make a reference to an Atomic object volatile. The whole point of the atomicinteger class is to provide a way to access and change an integer value safely. The only reason to make some variable volatile is because you intend to overwrite its value. Why overwrite the reference to the AtomicInteger when you can use its instance methods to update its value?

That’s why you are getting advice to make this variable final instead of volatile. Making the variable final nails down the reference so it can’t change, while making sure the reference contained by that variable is visible. The atomicInteger manages its own state in a threadsafe way so you shouldn’t have to overwrite the reference to it.

So it’s not exactly correct to say volatile is redundant here. But it is doing something that typically shouldn’t have to be done. Use volatile when you have to change the value contained in the variable. Use final when you shouldn’t be changing the value contained in the variable.